# Refused to load * because it appears in neither the img-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app, content-security-policy

In my index.html page I set:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

and also tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * data: https:; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

This is in a React app.  I got past the error with this meta tag on both the developer and production builds. However, when I deploy it on AWS, I get the CSP error again.  The static production build is being served from an S3.  The issue is only happening in Safari.

Full Error:

```
Refused to load data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTNweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxN3B4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTMgMTciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayI+CiAgICA8IS0tIEdlbmVyYXRvcjogU2tldGNoIDQzLjIgKDM5MDY5KSAtIGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuYm9oZW1pYW5jb2RpbmcuY29tL3NrZXRjaCAtLT4KICAgIDx0aXRsZT5fQXNzZXRzL0lubGluZS9Ta2lwQmFjazE1PC90aXRsZT4KICAgIDxkZXNjPkNyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBTa2V0Y2guPC9kZXNjPgogICAgPGRlZnM+PC9kZ...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 because it appears in neither the img-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Safari doesn't let you override the Content-Security-Policy using a meta tag, at least if it's already coming through in an HTTP header.  I removed the meta tag and updated the HTTP header and I got past the error.